# How to loop through a website and click on things that are not a button Selenium | BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I want to loop through [this site](https://www.booklooker.de/buecher-schnaeppchen) and click on each element in the list. That means for this example first on:

1. Die Päpstin
2. Leo Lausemaus will nicht teilen Pixi ...
3. Löcher - Die Geheimnisse von Green Lake
4. ...

and so on.

If I take a look on the html of the site I see, that list of elements are stored here:
[image]

respectively on element is here:
[image]

With the following code, I expected to get an array of objects with all the relevant elements:

```
driver.get('https://www.booklooker.de/buecher-schnaeppchen')
time.sleep(3)

elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tooltip')
for test in elements:
   test.click()
   time.sleep(5)
```

If i run that code snippet, it doesn't work; that is, nothing happened.

How can I:

1. get an array with the elements
2. and how to loop through them?

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I dont know, that i can accept a answer.

Comment: You should also explain what is your goal: what are you trying to achieve? Maybe there are less complex solutions (and we can avoid an XY Problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the space in your class name is not handled well by Selenium. What happens if you instead use:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.articleRow.resultlist_productsproduct')
```

Comment: Thank you, now i get list with objects, for example this is the first one:  

`<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="106c55eb-d277-4788-94d5-b2f54ce6c305", element="a9522a30-ac97-4cf5-8970-9b064b596a25")>`  

The problem is, i get a ElementNotInteractableException:  

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <tr id="article_A02A8f9001ZZl" class="articleRow resultlist_productsproduct"> could not be scrolled into view`    

So do you have an idea how to click that element?

Comment: What happens if you add `element.location_once_scrolled_into_view` before attempting to click?

Comment: Thank you, than i will get the same `ElementNotInteractableException`.   I edited my question.   When i go the class="tooltip" i get the href-tag with the link to the site. Do you know how is it possible to click that href-tag with the link?

Comment: So, your original question regarding the identification of your desired array has been solved. Could you kindly accept the above answer, then ask a new question if you continue to struggle with the Interactable Exception?

Comment: For shure. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help out!